# How to store values of dynamically added rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a form in which user can add more fields, as he want...

he can add 1,2,3,.... rows of fields..

the code that I use is here,

```
<?php
echo '
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="mod" value="'.$mod.'" />
   <table style="width: 700px">
   <tr>
       <th>Description</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>Price</th>
   </tr>';

// Loop to prepare the display of 100 product lines
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {

   if ($text['quantity'][$i] == "") $text['quantity'][$i] = 1;
   if ($text['unit'][$i] == "") $text['unit'][$i] = "0.00";
   // Display only the first line
   if ($nbr_ligne == 0) $nbr_ligne = 1;
   if ($i >= $nbr_ligne) $display = 'style="display:none"';
   echo '
   <tr id="cell'.$i.'" '.$display.'>
       <td>
           <textarea name="text[detail]['.$i.']">'.stripslashes($text['detail'][$i]).'</textarea>
           <br />
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(\'cell'.($i+1).'\').style.display=\'table-row\'; this.style.display=\'none\'">[+]</a>
       </td>
       <td>
           <input name="text[quantity]['.$i.']" id="q'.$i.'" value="" size="4" />
       </td>
       <td>
           <input name="text[unit]['.$i.']" id="u'.$i.'" value="" size="7" /> USD
       </td>
   </tr>';
}

echo '
   </table>
   <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
';
?>
```

the fields are adding successfully.

now I want to store the values of these fields in database.

the code I use for this is:

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    echo mysql_error($db);


       extract($_POST);
       $insert=mysql_query(" insert into add (description, quantity, price) values ('{$text['detail'][$i]}','{$text['quantity'][$i]}','{$text['unit'][$i]}')") or die("unable to insert"); 
}
```

but it does not work. plz help me guys. I need it very much.

Comment: There is no error but the values does not store in the database.

Comment: @Gapchoos : the output that displays on screen is "unable to insert"

Comment: Y don't u try 3 different variables for description, quantity and price.

Comment: @Gapchoos : can u give an example?

Comment: use a variable desc for descripion, quant for quantity and price for price. I guess the error occurs when the same variable value 'i' overlaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that $i has not been initialized in the script that you are using to save to the database. You will need to loop through from 0 to 100 and BREAK if a number does not exist. You're also using the [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) add. Use backticks ` on reserved keywords.

```
extract($_POST);

foreach(range(0,100) as $i){
    if(isset($text['detail'][$i]) && isset(isset($text['quantity'][$i]) && isset(isset($text['unit'][$i])){
         $insert= mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `add` (`description`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ('".$text['detail'][$i]."','".$text['quantity'][$i]."','".$text['unit'][$i]."')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Not too fond of the way you're looping on inserts, but the above piece of code should work, even though it's clearly not the best solution. A better way would be to create one singular INSERT query that inserts multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO example (name, age)
VALUES   ('John', 24),   ('Katrina', 21),   ('Michael', 22),   ('Hui Ling', 25),   ('Catherine', 29)
```

If you must loop on separate queries, you should use prepared statements for performance reasons.

Other issues:

1. You're open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
2. You're using the mysql functions, which are no longer recommended. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: no buddy. It also have the same output that is "unable to insert"... but thanx to help me. try something different to solve this. I think the problem is something else.

Comment: Instead of  or die("unable to insert") use  or die(mysql_error())

Comment: this is the error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add (description, quantity, price) values ('','1','0.00')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the mysql query in a loop if $i is equal to the nr of row added:

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
for ($e = 1; $e <= $i; $e++) {
$insert=mysql_query(" insert into add (description, quantity, price) values ('".$text['detail'][$e]."','".$text['quantity'][$e]."','".$text['unit'][$e]."')") or die("unable to insert"); 
}
}
```

Comment: This will result in a whole bunch of error notices being thrown.

Comment: @faq : no buddy. It also have the same output that is "unable to insert"... but thanx to help me. try something different to solve this.

Comment: @faq no. I doen't mean that. I mean, you tried very well and try again with something new or try again.